# In an Expo React Native app, how to pick a photo, store it locally on the phone, and later upload it to a Node.js service?

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, multipartform-data, multer

I'm building a React Native app with Expo, and I want to include the following workflow: The user takes a picture (either with the camera or picking one from the phone's gallery), which is stored locally on the phone, until the user uploads it some later time to a backend service.

I'm pretty stuck and would appreciate any pointers.

Here is what I have:

I use `expo-image-picker` to pick a photo from the phone's gallery:

```
const photo = await launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  base64: true,
  quality: 1,
});
```

Then I store the photo locally as a Base64 string using `expo-file-system`:

```
const location = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}${filename}`;

await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(location, photo.base64, {
  encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64
});
```

I keep information about the storage location, file name, and mime type in an `image` object. Later, I try to upload that image to my own Node.js backend service with `axios`, sending the following multi-part form data:

```
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('file', {
  path: image.location,
  name: image.filename,
  type: image.mimetype
} as any);
```

The backend service that receives the photo uses `multer`:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

router.post('/photo', upload.single('file'), async (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.file);
  ...
});
```

What arrives at my service is the following:

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '1653135701413.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpg',
  buffer: <Buffer >,
  size: 0
}
```

So no data is transferred. (It seems to be properly stored on the phone, because if I use the Expo filesystem's `readStringAsAsync`, I do get a pretty long Base64 string.)

What am I missing? Do I need to send the image as a blob? (If I try to do so, then `request.file` is `undefined`, so I guess I'm doing something wrong there as well.)

And in general, is there a better way to achieve this workflow in a managed React Native app? (For example, is it ok to store the image as a Base64 string, or would it be better to do this differently?)

**Edit:**

In the form data, I changed `path` to `uri`, and I switched from `axios` to `fetch`. Now the backend finally receives the image data.

Comment: is the ```buffer``` empty ? What do you get if you try reading the buffer

Comment: Yep, buffer length is 0.

Comment: While uploading image mime type is `image/jpg`? On the server can you try `var img = fs.readFileSync(request.file.path);`.

Comment: The backend service is a serverless function. (It will not store the image but upload it to Google Drive.) That's why I use `multer`'s in-memory storage.